# Relationship between $\min\{f \cdot g\}$ and $\min\{f\} \cdot \min\{g\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given real-valued continuous functions $f, g$, is the following (and why?) inequality true?

$$\min\{f \cdot g \} \leq \min f \cdot \min g$$

Can someone give me a proof?

Comment: Consider $f = g = x^2-1$.

Comment: Thanks...so I have to reverse the inequality. But is this generally true for an arbitrary number of functions?

Comment: Now consider $f = (x-1)^2+1, g = (x+1)^2+1$. $f\cdot g = x^4+4$. I believe your original inequality is true for general nonnegative functions.

Comment: but you are not sure?

Comment: It's pretty simple. $\min f \le f(x), \min g \le g(x)$. Hence $(\min f) (\min g) \le f\cdot g(x) \ \forall x$. This, however, holds only if $f,g$ are nonnegative. Else the inequality sign may get reversed, and we cannot draw a conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $\min(f) \leqslant f$ and $\min (g) \leqslant g$.  Now if $f, g$ are non-negative for all $x$ in its domain, we can conclude $\min(f) \cdot \min (g) \leqslant f\cdot g$, and taking minimum of both sides, $$\min (f) \cdot \min (g) \leqslant \min(f\cdot g)$$

which is really the opposite of what you have in the question.  If $f, g$ can take negative numbers, then the above logic does not hold, and it is not possible to conclude a similar general statement.